# How to read an 8bit bitmap's pixel colour and postion from byte array

Tags: c++, colors, position, byte, pixel

I currently have my 8bit bitmap's pixel data stored in an array of bytes: `BYTE* pixelData`.

How would I now go about coding my own function to return a pixel's colour by it's position? I've done a fair amount of searching and haven't found anything that covers this using C++.

Comment: You can access an element of an array using `pixelData[index]`.  What is the problem here?  Are you asking how to translate (x,y) coordinates into `index`?

Comment: I'm trying to figure out how I can loop through my pixel data by their x and y positions and access colour information.

Answer (score 1):

```
BYTE GetPixelColor(BYTE* src, int x, int y, int srcWidth)
{
    return src[y * srcWidth + x];
}

...
//suppose you have a 800 x 600 bmp, to get the color for pixel at x 30, y 200
BYTE color = GetPixelColor(src, 30, 200, 800);
```

Answer (score 1):

You can't, not enough data.  Almost all 8bpp pixel formats are indexed formats.  They use a color table that stores the actual RGB color, the byte at the pixel location is an index into that table.  The table contains 256 entries.

You'll also need a pointer to the color table.

Comment: I've also now begun storing my colour information like this:

RGBQUAD* colours;